# Unit of Work/Repository pattern and updating entities using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm trying to get to know UoW pattern a bit better as I like its concept, but currently I'm having a hard times saving entities.

The problem is that when my Edit (POST) action in my controller fires only parent entity gets saved and the child entities are intact i.e. I get the following error:

> Attaching an entity of type 'Access.Models.ApplicationParameter'
>   failed because another entity of the same type already has the same
>   primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or
>   setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any
>   entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because
>   some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key
>   values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state
>   to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

**Note:** Parent entity **Application** can have multiple child **ApplicationParameter** entities.

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ApplicationVM applicationVM)
    {
        Application application = ViewModelToModel(applicationVM);
        uow.ApplicationRepository.Update(application);

        foreach (var applicationParameterVM in applicationVM.ApplicationParameters)
        {
            ApplicationParameter applicationParameter = ViewModelToModel(applicationParameterVM);

            bool exists = uow.ApplicationParameterRepository.Exists(applicationParameter.idApplicationParameter);

            if (exists)
            {
                uow.ApplicationParameterRepository.Update(applicationParameter);
            }
            else
            {
                uow.ApplicationParameterRepository.Insert(applicationParameter);
            }
        }

        uow.Save();
        return View(applicationVM);
    }
```

**ApplicationParameterRepository.cs (just Update snippet)**

```
    public void Update(ApplicationParameter entity)
    {
        db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

**UOW.cs**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private AMEntities db = null;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        db = new AMEntities();
    }

    //Add all the repository handles here
    IApplicationRepository applicationRepository = null;
    IApplicationParameterRepository applicationParameterRepository = null;
    IApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository = null;

    //Add all the repository getters here
    public IApplicationRepository ApplicationRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (applicationRepository == null)
            {
                applicationRepository = new ApplicationRepository(db);
            }
            return applicationRepository;
        }
    }
    public IApplicationParameterRepository ApplicationParameterRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (applicationParameterRepository == null)
            {
                applicationParameterRepository = new ApplicationParameterRepository(db);
            }
            return applicationParameterRepository;
        }
    }
    public IApplicationUserRepository ApplicationUserRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (applicationUserRepository == null)
            {
                applicationUserRepository = new ApplicationUserRepository(db);
            }
            return applicationUserRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

**Question:**  What should I do to have those child entities saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options as far as I see it.

1. The easiest thing to do would be to get the entity at the start of your Edit action. If the result is null, then add a new one otherwise update the entity with the new values and save. This will ensure the parent entity and all children are in the same context.
2. The other way is to use self tracking entities. Take a look at [Self Tracking Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff407090(v=vs.100).aspx). This way you handle the state of your entities and not EF.

The issue is you have only set the state of the parent to updated, each childs state is still added, so its trying to add the child entities instead of update them.

Comment: That's the correct answer! Forgot to post the solution here, but #1 is how I solved it. The problem was that I was fetvhing the entities from the ViewModel which doesn't have all the information.

Comment: I am using ur method however it is not working wth automapper

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you establish the relationship between `applicationParameter` and `application`. There are at least three ways to do that using navigation properties or Ids, and I don't see in your code a line like this:

1.

```
// if application have unique Id, for example it already has been saved in db
applicationParameter.ApplicationId = application.Id;
```

2.

```
applicationParameter.Application = application;
```

3.

```
//if application is a EF-generated proxy 
application.ApplicationParameters.Add(applicationParameter);
```

Also, in simple cases you don't need to set `EntityState` if entity has been added to context properly.

Comment: I ignored the #1 one because that is something that is being done within the ViewModel itself (idApplication is passed directly to the ViewModel). I also tried #2 as applicationParameter.Application was null before, but unfortunately didn't help. #3 also didn't help as it adds already added entities.

Comment: @Agramer, do you have auto-increment on field `ApplicationParameter.Id` in db? If no, then `Id` should be set manually in code.

Comment: You led me to the right path, thank you! The actual problem was that instead of looping through the ViewModel's items I should've looped through the parent entity's items generated from the ViewModel. Will post the solution in a minute.